# changing image dynamically in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uiimageview

My problem is,
I have table of names. And when I touch on each name, a new view should appear and image of corresponding name. 
For all the names only one view should be there and the image should change dynamically.

Thank You.

Comment: Should we just commit our code to your repository also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a view controller with an `UIImageView`. Then I'd make the UIImageView a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *myImageView;
```

Then in the `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` method for the tableview delegate, you set the image property to the image view depending on the cell selected.

```
myViewController.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [Navigating a Data Hierarchy with Table Views](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH5-SW4) in the Apple docs.